# How to check if a solana token creator can change the name or picture of the token that he sold at dex?

Tags: solana-program, token, metadata, mint, authority

Unfortunately I bought a token at Dex which seems the dev rugged and left. Our community now has taken over the token.
I want to know if that dev can change anything now? (Including name of the token, token picture and etc...)

If we want to list this token at the CEX do we need to access this tokens solana development account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against using someone elses token you don't know for your community.

You can check if the token meta data is mutable in the solana explorer.
Here for USDC for example:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v/metadata

The person may also still have the mint and freeze authority. So he may be able to just mint more tokens.

You can still trade the token or provide liquidity to it on orca for example. To list on a CEX you would need to apply for it to be listed somehow. I would probably not do that if you don't actually own the token authority.

Comment: He doesn't have mint and freeze authority. But the ismutable has been set to int1 value. What does that mean? He can change the name or picture?

Comment: Yes as long as he has the authority and the meta data is mutable he can change it.

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer. Is there any way to find out if he still has authority or not? Is authority bound to anything like a wallet address?